# Qt Creator - How to get rid of "line too long" warning in python scripts

Tags: python, editor, settings, qt-creator

As the title suggests I wonder if it is possible to set the length of a line in python scripts when someone uses *Qt Creator* as an IDE, in order to get rid of this annoying warning: [image]

Comment: You either write short lines, deactivate or reconfigure the linter.

Comment: Where can I find the python *linter*  in *Qt Creator* and how I reconfigure it (or deactivate it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found at least how to hide these annotations (for Mac Os users):

First method is to go with the mouse on the top-left corner of the screen and to sequentially click *Qt Creator*->*Preferences*. Immediately the *Preferences* Dialog Window will appear inside the *Qt Creator* working window.

There, have to go to *Text Editor* in the left panel and in the right panel associated with *Text Editor*, in the horizontal tabs have to click on *Display* tab.

Scroll down and uncheck *Line annotations*.

The second and the third methods imply to place the mouse over one particular annotation (second method) or over one of the small yellow triangles which are shown in the left column of the "lines numbers column" (third method) and in both cases after one or two seconds will appear a floater and inside that floater with blue letters will be the "Annotation settings" message.

Clicking on that message will open the same *Preferences Window* like in first case. And there will be repeated the procedure described in the first case.