# Getting rid of errors and warnings in a python file in Qt Creator

Tags: python, qt-creator, underline

I am working on a python project in Qt Creator, and for some reason it keeps on underlining sections of my code, giving me flake8 warnings and errors.
[image]

By following this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65379557/qt-creator-how-to-get-rid-of-line-too-long-warning-in-python-scripts), I have managed to get rid of the labels coming out of the right side of the screen giving me warnings and errors, but I still find the underlining and warning icons on the line numbers very irratating. Is there a way I can get rid of this completely?

EDIT:
I have already ran `pip uninstall flake8` and the linting and underlining still persists in qt creator.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Comment: remove `flake8` and it should remove problem.

Comment: I have ran `pip uninstall flake8` and have successfully uninstalled it, however the linting and irratating underlines still persist.

Comment: @furas, well in this case a screenshot is the only way to demonstrate the issue I guess. It's not about the code itself but about the highlighting in the IDE.

Comment: if you use `flake8` then maybe read these warnings and make changes suggested in these warnings. I expect that line `#Change...` suggests one space after `#` so if you use`# Change...` then it should remove warning. And if you don't want to make suggested changes then uninstall `flake8`. Of course IDE may have built-in system for checking syntax and this may need to search option in settings and turn of it.

Comment: As I have said in the previous comment, I have already ran `pip uninstall flake8` and I can no longer access it from the command line, perhaps qt creator has it's own copy of the executable somewhere else? Anyhow, uninstalling `flake8` did not solve anything.  Is there any other solutions you could suggest I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Qt Creator does not support globally disabling warnings yet. However, you can try ignoring the Flake8 linter on specific files.

- **Ignoring the entire file**

  You can add this line to ignore all warnings in the file.

  ```py
  # flake8: noqa
  ```
- **Ignoring the specific lines**

  Or you can add this comment at the end of every line that you want to ignore errors on.

  ```py
  # noqa
  ```

### References

- [Qt Forum: Disable specific Python warnings](https://forum.qt.io/topic/123488/disable-specific-python-warnings)
- [Ignoring Errors with Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.1.1/user/ignoring-errors.html)